# Vintage.js: remote images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, vintagejs

Plugin only applies filter to files on my server, but with remote images:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It should be possible if the remote server explicitly allows access to the image data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is part of the browser's built-in security mechanisms to prevent hackers from using remote data to manipulate sites. You can't get around it (and if you could, it would be a major security hole that the browser makers would be very quick to fix)

To confirm this, the same question has already been [asked on the Vinatge.js website (as a github issue ticket)](https://github.com/rendro/vintageJS/issues/9), and the answer given by the Vinatge.js author was that it isn't possible to load remote images.

Sorry to disappoint you.

The work-around given was to use a proxy loader on your own server to load the images so that they are not given to the site as remote images.

In some cases, it may in fact be possible. It is possible for the remote server to be configured to allow it. However this configuration would need to be done on the remote server, so if you don't have access to that then the problem remains.